# Is the representation of dimension 2 of $SU(2)$ also a representation of the Lorentz group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

Is the representation of dimension 2 of $SU(2)$ also a representation of dimension 2 of the part connected to the identity of the group $SO(3,1)$?

To better explain my question:

The representation of dimension 2 of $SU(2)$ is given by exponentiation of the Pauli matrices:

$ U( \pmb{\epsilon}) = exp (i \pmb{\epsilon} \cdot \pmb{\sigma} ) $.

At the same time the Lorentz algebra has generators $J^{\pm, i}$ with $i=1, 2, 3$. The commutation relations are:

$[J^{+, i}, J^{+, j} ] = i \epsilon^{ijk} J^{+, k}$

$[J^{-, i}, J^{-, j} ] = i \epsilon^{ijk} J^{-, k}$

$[J^{+, i}, J^{-, j} ] = 0$.

This means that the algebra $so(3, 1)$ is just the algebra $su(2)$ "twice". Or in symbols: $so(3,1)=su(2) + su(2)$. When building the representation $(\frac{1}{2}, 0 )$ one maps $ J^{+, i} $ to the Pauli matrices and the  $ J^{-, i} $  to the null matrix, so they contribute nothing to exponential. This way one builds a representation of the part connected to the identity of the Lorentz group by exponentiation:

$\Lambda = exp (i \pmb{\epsilon} \cdot \pmb{\sigma}) $.

This is exactly the fundamental  representation of $SU(2)$.

Is my reasoning correct? If not, what did I miss?

Comment: It is correct. The $(1/2,0)$ representation is the left-handed Weyl spinor representation of $SO(1,3)$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: One more thing to add is that while the spin $1/2$ representation is a real representation of $SU(2)$, the $(1/2,0)$ rep of SO(1,3) is not real. This is because under complex conjugation $(J^{+,i})^\dagger = J^{-,i}$ so to make a real rep, you need to include $(0,1/2)$ as well.

Comment: I guess this is because when defining $J^{\pm, i}$ we took a complex linear combination of the generators, therefore we created a complex Lie algebra. Does it mean that while $\pmb{\epsilon}$ for SU(2) is real, for SO(3, 1) it is complex?